# For the life of me I can't understand this sentence from Anne McCaffrey's Dragonflight

Tags: meaning, grammar, books

> To forestall the incursions of the dreadful Threads, the Pernese, with the ingenuity of their forgotten Terran forebears, developed a highly specialized variety of a life-form indigenous to their adopted planet. ***Such humans as had a high empathy rating and some innate telepathic ability were trained to use and preserve this unusual animal whose ability to teleport was of great value in the fierce struggle to keep Pern bare of Threads.***

– Introduction

The confusing part for me is the beginning of the second sentence: "*Such humans as had a high empathy rating and some innate telepathic ability...*" -- specifically, "Such humans as had..." How is this supposed to be read?

Comment: What it means is that some humans were empathetic and also had telepathic ability.  Those humans could bond with the dragons -- or rather -- a human could bond with a dragon as it emerged from its egg -- and together they could fly and burn the Thread as it fell from the sky.  I think this will become clear as you read on.  Enjoy -- they are terrific books.  Specifically "The [relatively few] humans who had....were trained...."

Comment: Substitute 'Some humans who' for "Such humans as."

Comment: Rather, 'Those humans who ...'.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. I've never seen this phrasing before. Is it not commonly used any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted above "as" can function as a pronoun taking the place of that, who or which. M-W So, "Such humans who had a high empathy rating . . .

M-W Ex: "that kind of fruit as maids call medlars" --Shakespeare.